# C++ program's assertion failure due to deleting a pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have created an int variable.

Then I have assigned it to a pointer.

After that, I cout-ed it and then eventually I deleted.

What happens? The console pops up, but then immediately an error dialog box appear with the error  Assertion Failure. Can any one explain why I receive the error? Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int mainNum = 10;
    int *numPt;
    numPt = &mainNum;

    cout << &numPt; 

    delete(numPt);

    cout << endl << endl << endl; // this is to secure last newline char to be outputted.
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete stuff that is on the stack. You can only delete stuff that is on the heap (created by `new`). Otherwise all sorts of stuff will happen